# Passing Integer parameter to Jasper Report query gives SQL error operator does not exit : integer = boolean

Tags: java, postgresql, jasper-reports

I.m creationg a Jasper report using netbeans IDE, i'm not really good in Jasper reports
can some one please help me with this matter. also I'm using PostgreSQL

I have an interger parameter named hotelid

my report query is

select email as hotelEmail from hotel where id=$P{hotelid}

i get SQL error as operator does not exist: integer =boolean

i don't understand why is this, please some one help..

[image: Here's my Parameter]
[image: its an Integer]
[image: This is the problem i have]

Answer (score 0):

set Default Value Expression as 0 and it worked.